# Passing data between table views in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Trying to code for about us page using tableviews. I am able to create the first table view for "about us" components

```
 var aboutUs = ["About us", "Contact us", "Privacy policy"]
```

Have to pass on this items to next table view containing aboutUsDetails

```
 var aboutUsDetails = ["A team of docs and coders ","Contact us at editor@gmail.com","Privacy Policy will be updated soon"]
```

I have created the segue function like this

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if segue.identifier == SegueDetailsTableViewController
     {
    let detailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsTableViewController
        let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let row = myIndexPath.row
    detailViewController.aboutUsDetails = aboutUs[row]
}
```

I am a bit confused here because aboutUsDetails is a [String]; and it is not passing on? How do I overcome this?

Comment: It's a bit confusing, what are you trying to pass to the next ViewController? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Passing data from first tableview which contains three cells of aboutUs variable to next tableview that contains only one row as seen in var aboutUsDetails for each cell in first tableview @AhmadF

Comment: So, if I got it right, what are you doing is right, but why `aboutUsDetails` is an array of strings? you are saying that you need to pass only 1 value, so you should let it a string :)

Comment: Yes passing only one value but the above code isn't working and shows" cannot assign value of type 'String" to type [String]" @AhmadF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pass *only* one string, there is no need to declare `aboutUsDetails` property as an array of strings, instead let it be just a single string:

In `DetailsTableViewController`:

Change `aboutUsDetails: [String]?` to `aboutUsDetails: String?`

*If you are implementing the following code snippets, you should change them as follows:*

Change this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return aboutUsDetails.count
}
```

to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

And change this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // you might want to have a custom cell, you don't have to change it...
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellId")

    cell?.textLabel?.text = aboutUsDetails[indexPath.row]
}
```

to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // you might want to have a custom cell, you don't have to change it...
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellId")

    // this is part you should foucing on...
    cell?.textLabel?.text = aboutUsDetails
}
```

*Note: you might need to do Optional Binding to display the value of `aboutUsDetails` as it should (without "Optional("...")").*

---

**OR**

if you insist to declare aboutUsDetails as an array of strings (which I think that there is no need to do that), you will need to pass your string as an array containing one string, as follows:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == SegueDetailsTableViewController
        {
            let detailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsTableViewController
            let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let row = myIndexPath.row
            // here is the change, you are passing your string as the first
            // (and the only one) element of 'aboutUsDetails'
            detailViewController.aboutUsDetails = [aboutUs[row]]
        }
    }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Passing on only 1 value ---> different value for each of the item in first tableview..... About us ----> A team of docs and coders; Contact us ---->Contact us at editor@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

aboutUs[row] is a single string, aboutUsDetails seems to be an array of strings. You can either change aboutUsDetails to be a String, or pass your data like this:

```
detailViewController.aboutUsDetails = [aboutUs[row]]
```

Comment: Passing on only 1 value ---> different value for each of the item in first tableview..... About us ----> A team of docs and coders; Contact us ---->Contact us at editor@gmail.com This is the expected action for the app... What should be done ?

Comment: Thread1: Signal SIGABRT at let detailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsTableViewController

Comment: Should I need to change anything in DetailsTableViewController?

Comment: detailViewController.aboutUsDetails = ["test"] can you hardcode this and tell me if it works ?

Comment: i think you don't got error for this line 
      detailViewController.aboutUsDetails = [aboutUs[row]]
because it is error free code

Comment: replace this line: detailViewController.aboutUsDetails = aboutUs[row] with detailViewController.aboutUsDetails = ["test"]

Answer (score 0):

You need to only one changes and very small to below line

```
 detailViewController.aboutUsDetails = [aboutUs[row]]
```

because aboutUs[row] is string and [aboutUs[row]] is Array of String and you can not assign String to aboutUsDetails which is array of String.